# Math calculations with mixed types

Tags: java, math, casting

Only too often I found myself writing something like:

```
int part = 7;
int whole = 10;
...

int percentage = (int) (100.0 * (double) part/ (double) whole);
```

is there a way to reduce to minimum the number of casts (without actually modifying the original types of the variables ...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code in question is equivalent to:

```
int percentage = (int) (100.0 * part/ whole);
```

Arithmetic operations on double arguments give double results, so `part` and `whole` automatically converted to double

Answer (score 2):

The code in question is equivalent to:

```
int percentage = 100 * part / whole;
```

*with no floating point arithmetic whatsoever* thanks to how the casting conversion of double to int and integer division work. (If in the end you are throwing the fractional part out anyway, why bother calculating it.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cast, it will be casted automatically in your operation `100.0*part/whole` gives you a double value , just cast once in integer which will be final value

```
int percentage = (int) (100.0 * part/ whole);
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, `part/whole` would return an integer value. `100.0*part/whole` would return a double value though (Java will automatically cast part and whole to doubles, since 100.0 is a double)

Comment: yes exactly ,i think i missed 100.0  in my answer, updated, thanks for noticing